# How to get the Employee records in different scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my database to return the employee details from `Employee` table to my application.

```
SPHR_Employee_Get(@P_PK INT,@P_ACTIVE TINYINT)
```

`Employee` table structure is

```
EMP_PK INT, EMP_NAME NVARCHAR(200), EMP_ACTIVE TINYINT
```

Values for `EMP_ACTIVE`:   0 = InActive / 1 = Active

My requirement is: I need to get the employee(s) in the following scenarios, using the same procedure:

1. All employees
2. All active employees (`EMP_ACTIVE = 1`)
3. All inactive employees (`EMP_ACTIVE = 0`)
4. Only a particular employee (`EMP_PK = @P_PK`)
5. All active employees + a particular employee who's `EMP_PK = @P_PK` (even if that @P_PK employee is inactive) but no duplicate records.

My problem is, I can't change the signature of the stored procedure (sorry, I can't explain the reason here), that means I can't change/add the parameters and datatype in stored procedure / table. But I can change the body / query part of the stored procedure.

I know this may be a simple select query like

```
SELECT EMP_PK, EMP_NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE ?1 AND/OR ?2
```

But how can I manage the `WHERE` condition here? And what are the values I can pass to the existing stored procedure parameters from my application in the above 5 scenarios?

Note: `EMP_ACTIVE` column contains only `0` and `1` (0:InActive/1:Active). In my application , i know where i want apply all this scenarios, that is where I need to load all the employees or all the active/inactive employees etc. But I need to achieve this using the existing stored procedure only, I can't add an additional parameter to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

```
ALTER SPHR_Employee_Get(@P_PK INT,@P_ACTIVE TINYINT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EMP_PK, EMP_NAME 
    FROM EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE (EMP_PK = @P_PK OR @P_PK = -1);
      AND (EMP_ACTIVE = @P_ACTIVE OR @P_ACTIVE = -1)
END
```

Now execute it by sending different param values

```
--   All Employees
EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get -1, -1

--    All Active Employees
EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get -1, 1

-- All Inactive Employees
EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get -1, 0

-- Only a particular employee (EMP_PK = @P_PK)
EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get 123, -1

/*
All Active Employees 
+ a Particular employee who's EMP_PK = @P_PK (even if that @P_PK employee is inactive)
 - But no duplicate records.
*/
EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get -1, 1

EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get 123, -1
```

**Edit:**  from comments for 5th scenario

```
ALTER SPHR_Employee_Get(@P_PK INT, @P_ACTIVE TINYINT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@P_ACTIVE <> -2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT EMP_PK, EMP_NAME 
        FROM EMPLOYEE 
        WHERE (EMP_PK = @P_PK OR @P_PK = -1);
          AND (EMP_ACTIVE = @P_ACTIVE OR @P_ACTIVE = -1)
    END

    IF (@P_ACTIVE = -2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT EMP_PK, EMP_NAME 
        FROM EMPLOYEE 
        WHERE EMP_ACTIVE = 1
        UNION 
        SELECT EMP_PK, EMP_NAME 
        FROM EMPLOYEE 
        WHERE EMP_PK = @P_PK
    END
END
```

And call will be

```
 EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get 123, -2
```

**Edit 2:** Problem with TinyInt datatype

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPHR_Employee_Get(@P_PK INT, @P_ACTIVE TINYINT)
AS
BEGIN
    /*
        @P_ACTIVE VALUES in Different executions
        --1 All Employees
        --2 All Active Employees
        --3 All Inactive Employees
        --4 Only a particular employee (EMP_PK = @P_PK)
        --5 All Active Employees 
+ a Particular employee who's EMP_PK = @P_PK (even if that @P_PK employee is inactive)
 - But no duplicate records.

    */

    SELECT EMP_NBR, FIRST_NME 
    FROM EMPLOYEEPROFILE
    WHERE ((@P_ACTIVE = 1)
    OR (@P_ACTIVE=2 AND ACTIVE_IND=1)
    OR (@P_ACTIVE=3 AND ACTIVE_IND=0)
    OR (@P_ACTIVE=4 AND EMP_NBR=@P_PK)
    OR (@P_ACTIVE=5 AND ACTIVE_IND=1)
    )

    UNION 

    SELECT EMP_NBR, FIRST_NME 
    FROM EMPLOYEEPROFILE
    WHERE @P_ACTIVE=5 AND EMP_NBR=@P_PK

END
```

And the execution will be

```
--1 All Employees

EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get NULL,1

--2 All Active Employees

EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get NULL,2

--3 All Inactive Employees

EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get NULL,3

--4 Only a particular employee (EMP_PK = @P_PK)

EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get 123,4

--5 All Active Employees + Passed Emp(Active/Inactive)

EXEC SPHR_Employee_Get 123,5
```

Comment: Good, but here in the 5th scenario, i need to call the stored procedure in two times, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to it in a single call you need to change the body some another way. which is complex dynamic coding needed @AbdulRasheed

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion, +1 from me. So far this answer is best, I am waiting for a simple script to handle all this scenarios without any dynamic sql.

Comment: I have added single call code for 5th scenario without dynamic  @AbdulRasheed

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = -2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132255/discussion-between-abdul-rasheed-and-shakeer-mirza).

Comment: Please go throgh `Edit 2` @AbdulRasheed

Comment: Its working , thank you. And i got a simple query for this , i will post the same also an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and the suggestions from @Shakeer Mirza, resolved all the scenarios with a simple query.

```
SELECT  EMP_PK, EMP_NAME
FROM    EMPLOYEES
WHERE   (       EMP_PK      = ISNULL(@P_PK,EMP_PK)
            OR  EMP_ACTIVE  = ISNULL(@P_ACTIVE,EMP_ACTIVE)
        )
```

Parameter values for the scenarios is :

```
PK          Active          RETURNS
-------     -----------     --------
-1          NULL            All Records
-1          1               All Active Records
-1          0               All Inactive Records
PK_Value    2(>1)           Record for PK
PK_Value    1               All active records and the PK value record,
                            even if PK value record is inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this simple add an extra parameter in stored procedure to handle the required scenario.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPHR_Employee_Get
    @P_PK INT,
    @P_ACTIVE TINYINT,
    @P_Flag INT --- Add @P_Flag parameter to handle requested scanerio
AS
BEGIN

IF (@P_Flag = 1) ------- All Employees
BEGIN

Select EMP_PK,EMP_NAME, EMP_ACTIVE FROM Employees

END
ELSE IF (@P_Flag = 2) ----------- All Active Employees (EMP_ACTIVE = 1)
BEGIN

Select EMP_PK,EMP_NAME, EMP_ACTIVE FROM Employees
Where EMP_ACTIVE = @P_ACTIVE
END
ELSE IF (@P_Flag = 3) ------------ All Inactive Employees (EMP_ACTIVE = 0)
BEGIN

Select EMP_PK,EMP_NAME, EMP_ACTIVE FROM Employees
Where EMP_ACTIVE = @P_ACTIVE
END
ELSE IF (@P_Flag = 4) -------------- Only a particular employee (EMP_PK = @P_PK)
BEGIN

Select EMP_PK,EMP_NAME, EMP_ACTIVE FROM Employees
Where EMP_PK = @P_PK
END
ELSE IF (@P_Flag = 5) ------------ All Active Employees + a Particular employee who's EMP_PK = @P_PK (even if that @P_PK employee is inactive)- But no duplicate records.
BEGIN

Select Distinct EMP_PK,EMP_NAME, EMP_ACTIVE FROM Employees
Where (EMP_PK = @P_PK AND EMP_ACTIVE = 1) OR (EMP_PK = @P_PK AND EMP_ACTIVE = 0)
END


END
```

Comment: I can't add/change the stored procedure signature, that i already mentioned in my question.

Comment: Then how can you identify which scenario is execute within the same stored procedure.

Comment: I need to return the records to my application in the above mentioned scenarios, suppose in my application form i want to load all the active employees in a drop down and all the inactive employees in another drop down. I have only this two parameters to handle all this 5 scenarios.  I think to handle this 5 scenarios, i need to pass some values (some sort of combinations may be) in that two parameters and handle that in the where clause of the select query.